# java addActionListener not working

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to make it easier to make buttons by making a method, but when i use the method to make a button nothing happens when i press the button, even though i have a listener for the button

```
public void assignButton(Button wtf,String text) //program to assign buttons easily
{
    wtf = new Button(text);
    add(wtf);
    wtf.addActionListener(this);
}
```

i use assignButton(Check,"words"); to make the button

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) //checks if button has been pressed
{

    if(event.getSource() == Check)
    {
        code ++;
    }
    else
    {
        code = 2;
    }
   repaint();
```

every time i press the button it sets code to 2, anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Edit:

full code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PressSafeTemp extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
Button clear,Check;
int code = 0;
public void init() //assigns buttons
{
    clear = new Button("C");
    add(clear);
    clear.addActionListener(this);
    assignButton(Check,"words");
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawString(""+code,10,10);
}

public void assignButton(Button wtf,String text) //program to assign buttons easily
{
    wtf = new Button(text);
    add(wtf);
    wtf.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) //checks if button has been pressed
{

    if(event.getSource() == Check)
    {
        code ++;
    }
    else if(event.getSource() == clear)
    {
        code = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        code = 2;
    }
   repaint();
}
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a runnable example. Also remember, because of the way Java passes parameters, trying to assign a value to parameter will have effect on the value you passed it, instead, you should be returning the new instance of JButton and assigning it to your value instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I think you forgot an important "no" in that comment.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Fat fingers, small phone :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you pass `Check` to the method (as `wtf`) but then immediately set it to a new instance; this instance is *not* `Check`. It does get added but you can't get at it with `Check`.

You probably want to do...

```
Button getButton(String text) {
    Button button = new Button(text);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    return button;
}
```

and then `Check = getButton(someText);` followed by `add(Check);`.

If you don't actually need `Check` laying around, you could also just add it directly with `add(getButton(someText));`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what means for you `event.getSource() == Check` but that is the key, you need to check the correct comparison in your case. Something like for example:

`event.getSource().class.equals(JCheckBox.class)`